# insufficient virtual memory at run-time for Release but not for Debug version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fortran

I am using Intel Fortran compiler 11 with Visual studio 2010. My program crashes at run-time with the error "severe(41) insufficient virtual memory " but only with the Release version. The debug version runs smoothly, and in Task Menager (Windows 7) it allocates 1.7 GB of memory (working set (memory), while commit size is 1.9 GB). I have 8GB of memory in my laptop. Why is Debug running smoothly?
Thanks

Comment: You are right on the edge, the typical optimizations you get for the Release build (loop unrolling, inlining) that bloat code may well push you over that edge.  High time to consider building the x64 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The following assumes that, even though you have 8GB RAM on your laptop and you presumably have a 64-bit operating system, the executable created by Fortran is a 32-bit executable.*

1.9GB is very close to the maximum address space that a 32-bit process can access.  If your executable is large address aware and sets the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag, you can access more.

See: [Memory Limits for Windows and Windows Server Releases](http://IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE)

It would seem that the Release version is using just slightly more than the Debug version.  Perhaps there is a slightly different execution path on startup, or perhaps you are just using it slightly differently.  *Edit: @HansPassant correctly points out that some release optimizations give up some RAM for speed optimizations.*

Please observe memory allocation in Task Manager while you attempt to launch the Release version to confirm or refute this theory.

If the theory proves true, explore compiling for 64 bit and/or reducing your memory needs slightly.